# How to read a checkpointed DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, checkpoint

If I checkpoint a DataFrame like the below. How can I read it back in?

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('Abraham','Lincoln')], ['first_name', 'last_name'])
df1.checkpoint()
```

Something like....

```
reload = spark.read.something('checkpoints/87b411a8-19e3-402a-86a7-cfac0a4a6d14/rdd-40/*')
```

I see that the checkpoint file that is written to the checkpoints folder is partitioned but can't tell what the file type is.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: You can refer to the answer I wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250623/5650306