# PySpark - Read checkpointed DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, rdd, spark-checkpoint

i am currently using pyspark to perform some data cleaning for a machine learning application.
The last session crashed but i set up an checkpointdir and checkpointed my DataFrame.

Now i have checkpointed data directory in the form of:

```
id-of-checkpoint-dir/
\\- rdd-123/
\\- rdd-456/
```

The files in the rdd-subfolders seem to be hex files.

How can i read this checkpoint so i can cuntinue my data preparation instead of running the whole process again?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: Yes and no. You can not read the created checkpoint files when your session crashed. The files are there to help you during your runtime to be more fault tolerant. So i used  ended up using the function localCheckpoint(), to shorten my DAG and saved my intermediary data via parquet writer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to read checkpointed Dataframe, but know how to read checkpointed RDD. And you can use the following code to convert DataFrame to RDD.

```
rdd = df.rdd()
rdd.checkpoint()
```

The code for reading checkpointed RDD is as follows:

```
from pyspark.serializers import PickleSerializer, AutoBatchedSerializer
path = 'hdfs:///xxx/id-of-checkpoint-dir/rdd-123'
rdd = spark.sparkContext._checkpointFile(path, AutoBatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer()))
```

the definition of function `_checkpointFile` is as follows, **of which the parameter `input_deserializer` maybe need keep the same with class `RDD`**.
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/dd4db21cb69a9a9c3715360673a76e6f150303d4/python/pyspark/context.py#LL1674C8-L1674C8

```
def _checkpointFile(self, name: str, input_deserializer: PairDeserializer) -> RDD:
    jrdd = self._jsc.checkpointFile(name)
    return RDD(jrdd, self, input_deserializer)
```

for example, in spark 2.4.8, the deserializer is `AutoBatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())`
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.8/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD

```
class pyspark.RDD(jrdd, ctx, jrdd_deserializer=AutoBatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer()))[source]
```

while, in spark 3.4.0, the deserializer is AutoBatchedSerializer(CloudPickleSerializer())
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.html#pyspark.RDD

```
class pyspark.RDD(jrdd: JavaObject, ctx: SparkContext, jrdd_deserializer: pyspark.serializers.Serializer = AutoBatchedSerializer(CloudPickleSerializer()))[source]
```